# Loop through child and get attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a div which should replace the `select` element (because the real one is not necessary in that case) and I try to get the `data-select` attribute of each `option` (which represented by an `a` tag) but I probably do something wrong and I'm getting `null`. that's my code - HTML:

```
<div class="select" data-after="&#x43;">
    <i data-select-value="">Date &amp; Time</i>
    <div class="options">
        <a href="#" data-select="Date &amp; Time">Date &amp; Time</a>
        <a href="#" data-select="Alphabetical">Alphabetical</a>
        <a href="#" data-select="Modified">Modified</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="select" data-after="&#x43;">
    <i data-select-value="">Delete</i>
    <div class="options">
        <a href="#" data-select="Delete">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" data-select="Edit">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" data-select="Unpublish">Unpublish</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var selectbox = document.getElementsByClassName('select');
for(var i = 0; i < selectbox.length; i++) {
    selectbox[i].onclick = function() {
        var elechild = this.childNodes;
        var x = 0;
        for(x; x < elechild.length; x++) {
            elechild[x].onclick = function() {
                console.log(this.getAttribute('data-select'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this and get each attribute (please, no jQuery)?
(btw please excuse my english if I had any misspellings)

Thank you very much!

Comment: You are currently assigning the onclicks for the options in the outer div's onclick? Is that intentional? Anyway, the problem is that the children of the outer divs are the <i> and the <div>. You need `this.childNodes[1].childNodes` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can get all elements using `querySelectorAll` in javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Try this:

```js
var selectors = document.querySelectorAll('.options a');
   for (var x = 0; x < selectors.length; x++) {
  selectors[x].onclick = function() {
    console.log(this.getAttribute('data-select'));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="select" data-after="&#x43;">
    <i data-select-value="">Date &amp; Time</i>
    <div class="options">
        <a href="#" data-select="Date &amp; Time">Date &amp; Time</a>
        <a href="#" data-select="Alphabetical">Alphabetical</a>
        <a href="#" data-select="Modified">Modified</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="select" data-after="&#x43;">
    <i data-select-value="">Delete</i>
    <div class="options">
        <a href="#" data-select="Delete">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" data-select="Edit">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" data-select="Unpublish">Unpublish</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Console: `TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

You really had overthought that a bit. You only need to gather up the links and loop through them. You might have noticed that in your code, you had to click twice for anything to happen - - that was because you were applying a click event to ALL the children of the `select` `div` elements as well as the `select` `div` elements, which included the `option` div.

Also, it's better to not use the `onXyz` event properties of DOM objects and instead use the **[W3C DOM Event standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#introduction-to-dom-events)**, which uses `addEventListener` as an event callback registration method. This allows for a more standard and more robust event registration / de-registration model.

```js
// Just get the anchors that are children of your options element:
var selectAnchors = document.querySelectorAll(".options a");

// Just loop through the anchors. No need to loop the divs
for(var x = 0; x < selectAnchors.length; x++) {
  selectAnchors[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this.getAttribute('data-select'));
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="select" data-after="&#x43;">
    <i data-select-value="">Date &amp; Time</i>
    <div class="options">
        <a href="#" data-select="Date &amp; Time">Date &amp; Time</a>
        <a href="#" data-select="Alphabetical">Alphabetical</a>
        <a href="#" data-select="Modified">Modified</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="select" data-after="&#x43;">
    <i data-select-value="">Delete</i>
    <div class="options">
        <a href="#" data-select="Delete">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" data-select="Edit">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" data-select="Unpublish">Unpublish</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var options = document.querySelectorAll('.select .options a');
for (var x = 0; x < options.length; x++) {
  options[x].onclick = function() {
    console.log(this.getAttribute('data-select'));
  }
}
```